# How do you code a pivot table in Delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, database-design

I am simultaneously learning about databases (through Access), programming interfaces to db's (through Delphi), and linking the two (via MS's SQL)--so please forgive any newbie confusion here ... I'm using a teacher's gradebook as an example to help me learn. I understand the relationship between students and their assignment grades is many-to-many. I can set up the underlying tables and relationship, and I can query the underlying database.

What I can't figure out is how to display/report students and grades the way it's typically done in, say, a spreadsheet--students in rows, assignments in columns, grades in cells--with the added point that assignments are added as a course goes on; one does not know all assignments when planning the database fields.

One solution might be something equivalent to MS's pivot table concept. Is this easily done with Delphi? Does a simpler alternative exist? (Maybe make a separate table somehow with fields for student names and individual assignment names?)

Comment: Was Access database offered by your professor? I'm currently fighting with an large-n-boring lab on Access(after working with an Oracle db as developer for several years on my job) - IMHO Access is the worst choice for students to learn databases and database design at all. P.S. how do you access your database from delphi, i.e. what library you are using?

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit the data in the pivot too or is this display only?

Comment: @SamM -- ideally, editing too.

Comment: @Boris Treukhov -- I'm learning on my own, choosing Access because (a) I have it, (b) I'm interested in simple desktop applications, and (c) people around me use it. FWIW, I know my university's Comp. Sci. courses do *not* teach or work with Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Access, create a new query from the Query Wizard, then choose Crosstab Query Wizard. That effort should help you understand Access pivot query capabilities; there is no such thing in Access as a pivot *table*. Figure out the Access query you need, then figure out how to open that Access query from Delphi. At this point your question is about Access and Delphi is only incidental.

Comment: @AlC: Great that you are accepting answers to your questions! Did you know that you can both accept and upvote the answer?